# Unity 2017.3 building assetbundles takes to much time

Tags: unity-game-engine

Today I was building my assetbundles with 15 scriptable objects in Unity. It takes me about 10 minutes to build the assetbundles.

[image]

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may find the answer.

There are plenty of resources in my project, even though they are not be assigned to any assetbundle.